# How to include an external header file when I have 1 header for 2 .cpp files?

Tags: c++

I have one header file and two .cpp files.
E.g. normal.h, normal.cpp, abnormal.cpp.
I have included the header files in both the .cpp files.
Now I have an external header, say external.h. I included external.h in normal.h and abnormal.cpp.
But I am getting link errors. Kindly help me on how to include the external header file.

**This is my normal.h code**

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<external.hpp>

class normal
{
    public:
           normal();
           ~normal();
           void function();
           void Function();
 
};
```

**normal.cpp code**

```
#include"normal.h"
normal::normal(){
}
normal::~normal(){
}
```

**abnormal.cpp code**

```
#include"normal.h"
#include<external.hpp>
void normal::function()
{
 //external library's supported function call
}
```

**Errors**
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   LNK2005 "public: virtual void __cdecl
external::tools::Predicate_ite::reset(void)" (?reset@Predicate_ite@tools@aff3ct@@UEAAXXZ) already defined in abnormal.obj   trial3  F:\trial3\trial3\normal.obj 1

Error   LNK2005 "public: virtual bool __cdecl
external::tools::Predicate_ite::operator()(void)" (??RPredicate_ite@tools@aff3ct@@UEAA_NXZ) already defined in abnormal.obj trial3  F:\trial3\trial3\normal.obj 1

Error   LNK2005 "public: __cdecl
external::tools::Predicate_ite::Predicate_ite(int)" (??0Predicate_ite@tools@aff3ct@@QEAA@H@Z) already defined in abnormal.obj   trial3  F:\trial3\trial3\normal.obj 1

Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  trial3  F:\trial3\x64\Release\trial3.dll    1

Comment: There is nothing wrong about what you describe. You need to show to allow finding a problem. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Check the path of the external.h.

Comment: "_I am getting link errors_" - If you're getting link errors, you have missed to link with a library or object file an it has nothing to do with the inclusion of header files. Please include the exact link error in the question.

Comment: Exact error message please. What you need to do depends on the actual error you are seeing (amazingly enough). It may not be an error with the header files.

Comment: What you likely need are ***Header Guards*** to prevent multiple inclusions of the same header file. Search ***Header Guards***.

Comment: @Yunnosch - my bet is your guess was right `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I will incorporate the header guards into my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Feel free -- you have a good one.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Tahnks. Sorry for the late credits.

Answer (score 2):

Including headers into more than one code file is not a prolem.
There is nothing abnormal about a second code file including the same header.

Linker problems might arise from doing one of the following:

- including headers which contain code instead of only declarations, typedefs, macro definitions and implementations of templated classes
- the same applies to including code files
- including the same header more than once into the same code file (though that is not a problem in many cases); the adverse effect of this can be avoided with "header guards" also known as "reinclusion guards" (`#ifndef HEADERNAME_H` `#define HEADERNAME_H` `/* content */` `#endif /* HEADERNAME_H */` ), credits to David C. Ranking for bringing this up; a special case of this is to include the header twice by once including direclty and once indirectly via another header (which seems to be what you worry about)

Linker problems can also occur unrelated to header including, if the smybols are only declared but not defined, e.g. when the corresponding libraries are not correctly added to the project (thanks to Ted Lyngmo for bringing that up).

Other problems than linker problems might arise from:

- includiong headers with conflicting/contradictory content
- circular inclusions
- unsolved dependencies caused by including headers in the wrong order which wrongly have a dependency on their order

Comment: Aishwarya Siva, I would target the specific problem of your situation if you provide a [mre],.Otherwise you have to find it yourself with my generic list.